# Cloud Functions overview chart showing a constant flow of errors while errors tab and logs don't show any errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I believe the screenshot is quite self-explanatory. Is there some other place I could look for those errors or is it possible that in reality there are no errors?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can enter into the [functions logs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging) in order to see the executions and see if there are no recent errors. Maybe it's a matter of no errors in the time frame you are checking with the graphs.

Comment: As mentioned in the question title, logs don't show any errors. Also, as you can see in the screenshot, the selected time frame does show errors in the chart.